# Get error description from caught error

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch

I do something like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do
{
    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
}
catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted
{
    let descr = ???
    Log.error("Failed to decode JSON response. Error was: \(descr)")
}
```

how can I access the error description from this? Why can I not simply catch any kind of error in one catch and access its debug description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to access the error description

In Swift, a lot of the errors conform to the protocol `LocalizedError`, which will give you a variable `localizedDescription: String?` that you can use to print an error message. `DecodingError` should not be any different.

#### How to catch any kind of error

You should be able to catch any kind of errors in one catch. In order to do this, you can use

```
catch let error as DecodingError {
    // Any error of type DecodingError
}
```

or

```
catch {
    // Any possible error
}
```

### Putting it all together

If I understand correctly, you are tring to catch any error of type `DecodingError`. In that case, you can simply do the following

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(type, from: data)
} catch let error as? DecodingError {
    Log.error("Failed to decode JSON response. Error was: \(String(describing: error.localizedDescription))")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!